# Deadlock between Git Pull & Git Push

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-push, git-pull

It's shared GIT repository. Many people working on Same git Repository.

That's why i have tried first `git pull` to get other changes then `add, commit & push`.

I have tried below commands on my local

```
$ git pull
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

File Name

Please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

For Commit

```
$ git commit

no changes added to commit
```

For Push

```
$ git push
To ssh://git@ab.com:2222/diffusion/SMM/abc.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@ab.com:2222/diffusion/SMM/abc.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: check status by $git status and add and commit new and modified files then try $git pull origin master

Comment: @AswathyS How, exactly, would that help?!

Comment: @AnkitShah Did you try *adding* before committing?

Comment: What is you `git status`? Does it list untracked files?

Comment: Yes @Biffen i tried my New Folder to Add before Committing. After adding that new folder trying to commit.

Comment: @AnkitShah I don't quite believe you, since Git is saying ‘*no changes added to commit*’.

Comment: @das_j git status says Untracked files:(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  Lots of file names & in end no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: Confused what actually will do now. Know done Mistake but how to solve it

Comment: @AnkitShah Which part do you not understand? You have local changes. A pull would clash with those changes. You'll have to either commit them or revert them. If you wish to commit them you'll have to add them first (hence ‘*use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed*’).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. You probably have this file ignored (`.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`) or you assume it was unchanged (`git update-index --assume-unchanged`).

You can use `git check-ignore -v "File Name"` to check if the file is ignored.
If `ls "File Name` returns no error, the file is there but assumed unchanged by git. You can use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged` to assume it was changed.

Comment: Yes have `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that there are untracked files in your working directory which you also try to pull.

So the file `Some File` is in your working directory but somebody pushed a file with the same name to the server. When you pulled, it would overwrite your local file with the version from the remote repository: `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge`.

To solve this problem you can do two things:

- Move the file away, pull, have two versions laying around
- `git add` the file, `git commit` it and `git pull` to merge your local changes with the upstream

Also, read about the [staging area](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States). You need to add the files to the staging area before committing. This is why `git commit` tells you that there is nothing staged for commit. `git commit` only commits what you put to the staging area.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a time to understand how git works (good resource [1]). In particular, being able to see entire git history is crucial, use following command or git UIs for that (`gitk`, `git-gui`):

`git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate`

In short, probably: `git pull --rebase` will work for you (if you don't have conflicting changes).

[1] https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2